# In a star scheme, How to define the fact table when the data has different levels of dimensions?

Tags: star-schema, powerbi

In a PowerBI project, I need some help to define the fact table/s.
Eventually, I would like to have a nice star scheme to preset some basic visuals as stacked bar etc. to the client.

I'm new to BI and I'm afraid that I'm missing here something very obvious.

## Description of the data

I have data stored in a tables:
**City**, **Company**, **Budget**, **CategorizedBudget** and **Expense**.

The **City** table contain city name and region.

| ID | City | Region |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | RocksVille | Center |
| 2 | GoldCity | North |

The **Company** table contain company name and city.

| ID | Company | FK_CityID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Nissan | 1 |
| 2 | Herosh LTD | 2 |

The **Budget** table contain companies annual budget amounts.

| ID | FK_CompanyID | Year | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2019 | 1000000 $ |
| 2 | 1 | 2020 | 1400000 $ |

The **CategorizedBudget** table contain **some** of the annual budget amounts of those companies, divided by categories

| ID | FK_BudgetID | Category | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Category A | 400000 $ |
| 2 | 1 | Category B | 300000 $ |
| 3 | 1 | Category C | 300000 $ |

The **Expense** table contain tertile budget amounts of those companies, divided by categories.

| ID | FK_CompanyID | Year | Tertile | Category | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2019 | 1 | Category A | 100000 $ |
| 2 | 1 | 2019 | 1 | Category B | 100000 $ |
| 3 | 1 | 2019 | 1 | Category C | 150000 $ |
| 4 | 1 | 2019 | 2 | Category A | 150000 $ |
| 5 | 1 | 2019 | 2 | Category B | 50000 $ |
| 6 | 1 | 2019 | 2 | Category C | 150000 $ |
| 7 | 1 | 2019 | 3 | Category A | 100000 $ |
| 8 | 1 | 2019 | 3 | Category B | 150000 $ |
| 9 | 1 | 2019 | 3 | Category C | 50000 $ |

## Expected Result

The visuals should be:

1. Stacked Column Chart that show sum of the annual **budget** amounts for the companies city regions
   [image]
2. Stacked Column Chart that show sum of the annual **expenses** amounts for the companies city regions
   [image]
3. when drilling to the **expenses**, show the amounts by tertiles.
   [image]

## Dimensions

It appears that the dimensions are: **Date** (year, tertile), **Location** (city, region), **Category** (name), **Comapny** (name)

## Fact/s

The fact is where I'm getting confused. I thought about some practices:

### First thought

Merging **Budget** and **CategorizedBudget** and **Expenses** into one fact.

| ID | FK_CompanyID | Year | Tertile | Category | ExpensesAmount | BudgetAmount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2019 | 1 | Category A | 100000 $ | ? |
| 2 | 1 | 2019 | 1 | Category B | 100000 $ | ? |
| 3 | 1 | 2019 | 1 | Category C | 150000 $ | ? |
| 4 | 1 | 2019 | 2 | Category A | 100000 $ | ? |
| 5 | 1 | 2019 | 2 | Category B | 100000 $ | ? |
| 6 | 1 | 2019 | 2 | Category C | 150000 $ | ? |

But the budget annual amounts are not divided to tertiles.

### Second thought:

Merging the **Budget** and **CategorizedBudget** to one fact and getting the Expenses as one fact.

| ID | FK_CompanyID | Year | Category | BudgetAmount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2019 | Category A | 100000 $ |
| 2 | 1 | 2019 | Category B | 100000 $ |
| 3 | 1 | 2019 | Category C | 150000 $ |
| 4 | 1 | 2020 | Category A | ? |
| 5 | 1 | 2020 | Category B | ? |
| 6 | 1 | 2020 | Category C | ? |

But some of the budget annual amounts are not categorized.

### Third thought:

Use three facts for **Budget** and **CategorizedBudget** and **Expenses**
[image]

But it looks not starry at all.. and I'm afraid It will be complicated if I'll have to add more fact and dimensions later.
It also feel like I'm duplicating something here.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You don't have "different levels of dimensions". Your fact is the most granular bit of information, everything else is just aggregation (by category and year). Note that your sample data don't add up, which is precisely why you shouldn't persist aggregated values.

Comment: @mustaccio, 1. About the question header, I didn't find any better expression to explain my question. Do you have any edit suggestion for that? 2. You're saying that the fact is the most granular bit of information, Does that mean that I should handle with the three facts?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this star schema:

[image]

Classic layout, dimensions are denormalized and one fact with one granularity.
There is no need of date dimension

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How would I store a year level amount? null quarter?

Comment: I do not like nulls. You can have 2 dims (year, quarter) and have 2 field in the fact and have an id for a new row in the quarter that means all quarters